# Visual C++ / Visual Studio settings. What is calling for MSVCR120D.DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

[image]Background.  I ran a release version of my program on another computer and immediately got a message, "Could not find Your_DLL.dll or one of it's dependencies".  I believe I've tracked this down to the fact that "Your_DLL.dll" makes use of MSVCR120D.DLL .  I checked this using Dependency Walker (Depends.exe).  On my original computer, all is well because I have the full Visual Studio (2013) and MSVCR120D.DLL is present.  However, it is not present on another machine, nor should it be as it's a Debug version of MSVCR120.DLL.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out where in my project for "Your_DLL" I am making use of MSVCR120D.DLL or have any debug settings under the release build. A search for MSVCR120D.DLL in the whole directory turns up nothing.  Of course, perhaps something in the settings for the release build is somehow making use of a debug dll that in turn calls this debug dll.  Can someone give me a clue where to look for the problem?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: What does the build configuration manager say when you set the active build configuration to Release.

Comment: cup, thanks for getting back so quickly. I tried to show a picture to show what it says.  The title is "Configuration Manager".  If Acitve Solution Configuration is Release, Active solution platforms is x64 and the dll in question shows as Configuration "release" and platform x64

Comment: Are you running the 64bit version or the 32 bit version?  If there is a 32 bit configuration, check what the 32 bit configuration says

Comment: Debug builds always use the debug versions of the redistributable DLLs, release builds the release redistributable DLLs (this should be the default).
If you plan on deploying a debug build to a non development machine you must deploy the debug redistributable as well. The easiest way is to copy them into the same directory as your executable/DLL.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Note that, under most circumstances, debug DLLs [are not redistributable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx) as this violates the license conditions. If you need a debug environment on another PC, you need to install a version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Simon and Roger.  It is not my intention to distribute a debug build, nor do I want any of the dlls/libs to be debug. I want to track down why this dll is dependent on a debug dll.  I'm not the only one who has access to the code, so someone else could have changed a setting that I'm not seeing (or I could have accidentally done it myself!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers.  We found the problem, and I must admit that I'm the one who caused it!  "Your_DLL.dll" was building just fine in Debug and Release.  The problem was how I was using it from another dll.  The other dll was a C# project and under references, I added "Your_DLL.dll".  Unfortunately, I left the "Copy local" to True.  By company policy, we build everything to a central place C:\bin\debug or C:\bin\release.  Also, by company policy, when we add a reference, we pick the debug version (you have to pick one!) but make sure to have "Copy Local" as FALSE.  So when our build script builds, it correctly builds "Your_DLL.dll" and puts a release version in C:\bin\release.  However, when CSharp.dll is subsequently built, it was putting a debug version of "Your_DLL.dll" in C:\bin\release.  We finally noticed the problem when we saw that the version of Your_DLL.dll was the same size in c:\bin\debug and c:\bin\release.

I've always had a sinking feeling about the way we handle references.  Perhaps there is a better way?  But that's probably a whole other stack overflow question.

I hope this helps someone in the future.
Thank you,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

The flavor of a run-time library is specified in the compiler switch /M...

For dynamically linked CRT, it should be **/MD** for release config, and **/MDd** for debug. I would check that first, by looking into:

Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

[added]
The Depends tool has a "Profile" command (Profile -> Start Profiling), where you can see a run-time information for dynamically loaded DLLs. Hope that will point you to the offender.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked and it is indeed /MD (not /MDd).  Any other places to check?

Comment: @Dave - if you are pulling other dlls - you'd have to check the same for them.

Comment: Yes, all other dlls seem to have settings as /MD.  There are some statically linked libs created by running the Matlab Compiler.  Is there a way to tell if a .lib is dependent on debug  stuff?  Depends.exe seems to squawk when I open a .lib.  Thanks

Comment: Static libs are linked to either DLL or executable, so that DLL or executable will depend on debug runtime. Use "Profile" in dependency walker as suggested to find who tries to load it.